# How to get Maximum Duration Using Kafka Streaming

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application where videos are sent on a kafka topic. Each video has an id, a duration, a title and a description. My requirement is, after consuming stream of videos from one topic, to return one video with the maximum duration. How could this be achieved using Kafka KStream and or KTables?

```
public class video{
   Integer id;
   String title;
   String description;
   Integer durationInSeconds;
   ...
}
```

Comment: You can refer the example : https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.3.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/KafkaMusicExample.java

Comment: That is exactly my question, in that example there is `MIN_CHARTABLE_DURATION` I need to get the maximum duration so I can calculate the minimum duration to filter out the videos that have a duration under the minimum, thanks for bringing this up

Comment: How do you know that _"after consuming stream of videos from one topic"_ since a topic is an unbounded set of records and there's simply no way it's finished? If you know that a certain record is a marker to finish a set of videos, you could use groupBy over sessions.

Comment: Yes I should have said while* consuming a stream, because I need to keep the stream history of all the videos consumed and recalculate the maximum duration. I am new to Kafka so excuse my lack of explaining correctly my requirement